# How to definine a function, when it contains the integral of the function itself?

Tags: integration

My question is basically if it is possible to define the following function. I tried in GeoGebra which solely says it is a circular definition, which I understand, however I do strongly believe that there most be one way or another ot calculate this. It is for a model of how the in and outflow of the Mediterranean behave - I a very thankful for any help!

$V(t)=\int{\sqrt{\sin{t}-V(t)}dt}$

(full equation: $V(t)_{c}=A_{cs}\int{\sqrt{2g(a \sin{(t)}+c-\frac{V(t)_{c}+V_{M}}{A_{M}})}dt}$

Where this is basically water flowing from one bucket to another and back when one of which's height changes sinusoidally and the other in reaction to the first one.)

I am sorry for the most probably very fundamental nature of the question, however I couldn't find anything related to that in the forum.

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: What you have there is a specific [integral equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation), which is, more-or-less, a differential equation in reverse.  There are techniques for solving such equations, though it might be helpful to know where you encountered this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response!

It was about a simple approach in tackling the tides in the Mediterranean. I left out all the constants, but it comes down to the fact that the speed of the flow is dependent on the difference in height and hence on how much water flowed up to a certain point in time.

Comment: If you derivate your equation, you find $\frac{dV}{dt}=\sqrt{\sin t-V}$ which is a non-circular differential equation for $V$. But a non-linear one, so good luck with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write is a integral equation, which can be easily be turned to an ordinary differential equation by differentiation.

$$V'(x)=\sqrt{\sin t-V(t)}$$ or

$$V'^2(t)+V(t)=\sin t.$$

(We have many more techniques for solving ODEs than integral equations.)

Unfortunately, this one resists to resolution.